# Can Lactobacillus ferment solely with table sugar?

Tags: fermentation, equipment, techniques, ingredients, sugar

I'd like to create an anaerobic ferment with just lactobacillus (i.e. no yeast), table sugar and water.

Is this possible or would I have to add anything else to help the Lactobacillus ferment?

Answer (score 1):

It would need some Amino Acids, or at least some nitrogenous compounds to make AAs from. It would ferment some what with out, but it will need some nitrogenous compounds to grow and thrive.